# How do I move the window buttons of Google Chrome to left?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 13.04, window-buttons

I updated Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 using Gnome Shell 3.6. After the update, the window buttons from e.g. Google Chrome are displayed on the right side (close, minimize, maximize).

In 12.10, I believe I managed to placed them on the left side with:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,maximize,close"
```

but the whole metacity branch is missing.

How can I achieve the same effect in 13.04? I don't want to use the system title bar and borders.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not. The answer proposed in http://askubuntu.com/a/113995/60333 doesn't work for me anymore.

Comment: What about `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout ":close,minimize,maximize"`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that just moves the buttons of native gnome windows and not the integrated buttons of Chrome.

Comment: This would then be a duplicate of [How come all my window buttons are right aligned, but chrome buttons are on the left?](http://askubuntu.com/q/244035/) but you say that option is unavailable. I am reopening this question because I overlooked a few things.

Comment: that is right, that is the old solution, but the whole gconf branch /apps/metacity/ is missing now after the upgrade

Comment: I've put a bounty on the original question to see if someone knows what changed.

Comment: I can confirm the solution http://askubuntu.com/a/244099/60333. Only difference: I wanted the buttons to show on the LEFT side, so the command is: gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "close,maximize,minimize:"