# How to place window controls in chromium/chrome to the left side?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, window-buttons, openbox

Anyone knows how to do it?
It doesn't inherits openbox's settings so i tried advices, related to other unity/gnome (maybe chrom* inherits it):

```
$ gconftool-2 --get /apps/metacity/general/button_layout
close,minimize,maximize:
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
'close,minimize,maximize:'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout
No such schema 'org.gnome.shell.overrides'
```

But buttons still on the right side. And I still don't want additional useless native decorator.

Answer (score 25):

Looks like you have not enabled setting "Use System Title-bar and Borders".

Go to Settings in Chrome/Chromium > Search for this option and check-mark it.

[image: Chrome Settings]

**Update**

While above solution will use native window frame, if you want to avoid using that, you can have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/244099/12242) answer. If it still doesn't solve the problem, I believe it is something to do with OpenBox which doesn't use Metacity decorator.

Comment: I wrote 'And I still don't want additional useless native decorator.'. It means i wanna use chrom* **without** native decorator. So don't advice me to turn it on :)

Comment: It takes about 1 cm of additional vertical space.

Comment: @actionless: Totally missed out on that, updated my answer.

Comment: in question i copied gconf/gsettings output -- it looks like in it in answer you referencing to -- so i have no idea, from which system settings chrom* gets these settings.

Comment: Btw, ubuntu doesn't use metacity too. So it very  strange, why changing metacity settings helps chrom* in unity, but doesn't helps in openbox. But whatever thank you for trying to assist.