# Move Chromium button layout from right to left

Tags: unity, 16.04, google-chrome, chromium, window-buttons

For a while now, I was able to use the instructions from one of the comments in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/244099/60869) answer to align Chromium's Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons to the left of the browser window.

However, in Chromium 52.0 on 16.04 the button layout remains at Minimize, Maximize and Close on the right.

I've entered this command in the terminal with no success.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "close,minimize,maximize:"
```

How can I move Chromium's button layout from right back to left?

Comment: What DE are you using?

Comment: @Matteo I'm using Unity.

Comment: Have you chosen "use GTK theme" in the settings?

Comment: @MatteoP. Yes, with no success. And I'm not interested in the system title bar option as it takes up unnecessary screen real estate.

Answer (score 0):

Issue no longer present on Chromium 55.0.2883.87 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

[image: Chromium Button Layout fixed]

Comment: The problem is back on Chromium 59.0.3071.109 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

Comment: Issue fixed on 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)